# IIS in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: iis-7

Please explain about IIS 7 configuration in Visual studio 2008 
Describe the construction program for the Virtual Directory Web Appliction right way and run it

I have a problem when run program web app.The configuration of IIS Daily

Please help me to
Tanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: [Using Visual Studio 2008 with IIS 7.0](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/387/using-visual-studio-2008-with-iis-70/).